# Sort XSL, XML based on ID

Tags: xml, xslt

This is what I have so far, I would like to print comments by sorting ID but I do not want to print ID, only comments

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="CatCom/comments">
    <xsl:if test="(contains(., 'EDI'))">
        <xsl:element name="DetailNotes">
            <xsl:element name="Note"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Data structure for CatCom is

```
ID      comments 
1232    PACK:
3454    EDIQI
1233    Updated  Quantity
2344    SKU
4543    Updated  Quantity
6654    PACK:
5464    EDIQUK
6786    Updated  Quantity
6845    Updated   Shipped
```

Comment: For readability, consider using literal result elements: `<DetailNotes><Note><xsl:value-of select="."/></Note></DetailNotes>`

Comment: Can you please post the input data in its actual XML form?